# Is there a word specifically referring to the stand upon which a large book is displayed, opened to a page?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm thinking in particular of dictionaries or illuminated bibles being displayed on these stands, which are at least waist-high on a standing person, constructed of wood.  Is there a particular word for this, other than "book stand"?

Comment: My search turned up "book stand" and "dictionary stand".  Also, "book holder".

Answer (score 8):

A [lectern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lectern) is a reading desk, with a slanted top, usually placed on a stand or affixed to some other form of support, on which documents or books are placed as support for reading aloud.

Comment: Yup, a lectern could be a book stand, although probably a little pricier since it is frequently adjustable for height and pitch of the top where the book or materials would be placed.  They are frequently wired for light and/or sound, also.

Answer (score 2):

It is just a display book stand.  You might need a lectern or Shtender (for DavidM) if the main purpose was someone reading at the "stand".

Also if it is for a Bible and you want something grand then you may want an ambo or pulpit.

Comment: A [shtender](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12177) is a lectern.

Answer (score 1):

"Book stand" is the natural choice.

A tall book stand such as you describe is a "freestanding book stand". [Woodform, Inc](http://www.google.de/imgres?biw=1366&bih=600&tbm=isch&tbnid=NVJvEAZE5w-6CM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.woodform.com/book_stands.htm&docid=mOeqYiMZNSsltM&imgurl=http://www.woodform.com/book_s4.jpg&w=1651&h=2571&ei=4A8ZU_z6K4fNsgaulIDgAw&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=2559&page=1&start=0&ndsp=20&ved=0CHYQrQMwCA). uses this term, and they seem to know what they're talking about! They also refer to a "dictionary stand".

Otherwise, a "[podium](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/podium)" is

> a stand with a slanted surface that holds a book, notes, etc., for
>   someone who is reading, speaking, or teaching

Or, if you want get poetic, there is "pedestal" or "plinth".

Answer (score 1):

Various terms are used:

**Book cradle** of **book exhibition cradle** ([source](http://www.carrmclean.com/CategoryGroupBrowser.aspx?CategoryID=200&GroupNo=1945), [source](http://parkslibrarypreservation.wordpress.com/2010/08/05/making-book-cradles/)) are used for museum displays.

A tradename for a purportedly superior book cradle is the Benchmark Butterfly **Bookmount**. ([source](http://www.benchmarkcatalog.com/main-bbb.htm))

A search of *[book cradle](http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=book%20cradle&qpvt=book%20cradle&FORM=IGRE)* shows that *book stand* (mentioned by nxx) is also used, apparently for less demanding displays.